# K8S monitoring stack configuration with alerts

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, grafana, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to set up a k8s monitoring stack for my on-premises cluster. What I want to set up is:

- Prometheus
- Grafana
- Kube-state-metrics
- Alertmanager
- Loki

I can find a lot of resources to do that like:

- This configures the monitoring stack except Loki using their own CRD files:
  https://medium.com/faun/production-grade-kubernetes-monitoring-using-prometheus-78144b835b60
- Configure Prometheus and Grafana in different namespaces using separate helm charts:
  https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus
  https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana
- Configure Prometheus-operator helm chart into a single namespace:
  https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator

I have doubts regarding the configuration of the alert notifications.

- All three setups mentioned above have Grafana UI. So, there is an option to configure alert rules and notification channels via that UI.
- But in the first option, Prometheus rules are configured with Prometheus setup and notification channels are configured with the alert-manager setup using configMap CRDs.

**Which is the better configuration option?**

What is the difference in setting up alerts via Grafana UI & Prometheus rules and channels via such configMap CRDs?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both methods?

Comment: Could you also let us know where your cluster is? Cloud provider, Minikube, Kubeadm? Do you want to monitor specific metric or its just for general cluster monitoring?

Comment: @PjoterS As of now, I need general monitoring for the cluster, nodes, pods, containers..etc. I have an on-premises cluster setup using the kube-spray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose the third option to setup prometheus-operator in a namespace. Because this chart configures prometheus, grafana, and alertmanager. Prometheus is added as a datasource in grafana by default. It allows adding additional alert rules for Prometheus , datasources, and dashboards for grafana using chart's values file.

Then Configured Loki in the same namespace and added it as a datasource in grafana.
Also configured a webhook to redirect the notifications from alertmanager to MS teams.

Comment: Can you provide details on notifications/alerts configurations? I am newbie to Prometheus/Grafana and installed recently and working on setting up LDAP access and notifications/alerts?

Comment: @cnu I configured alert rules by configuring alertmanager of Prometheus operator chart ( the chart link is in the question).The alertmanager.config helm parameter of the chart can be used to declare custom configs for Alertmanager. Also, added a prometheus-msteams receiver in the alertmanager config which will make a teams channel in microsoft teams to recieve alert notifications. This is a link to that chart: https://github.com/prometheus-msteams/prometheus-msteams . You can also setup other receivers like slack instead of MS teams.

Comment: Got it, will check alertmanager.config and update accordingly as we're looking at email alerts only at this time. Do we need to uninstall and re-install all the charts, or is there a way to update alert manager pods alone with helm?

Comment: @cnu I think, in that chart, alert-manager configuration values are loaded to a secret. So restarting the alert-manager pod or something may not reflect the configuration changes. Better reinstalling the chart. ( Or you can try modifying that particular k8s secret. I'm not sure if that'll work or not.)